# Let $R$ be a simple ring having a minimal left ideal $L$. Then every simple $R$-module is isomorphic to $L$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> **Lemma** : Let $R$ be a simple ring having aminimal left ideal $L$. Then every simple $R$-module is isomorphic to $L$.

**Proof** : Let $M$ be a simple R-module. By simplicity of $R$ we have $LR = R$. Hence $LM \supseteq L(RM) = (LR)M = RM \neq 0.$ Choose $m \in M$ such that $Lm \neq 0$. Since $Lm$ is a submodule of $M$ it follows that $Lm = M$. The map $\varphi : L \longrightarrow M$ given by $ϕ(l) = \varphi m$ is therefore a surjective $R$-module homomorphism. Its kernel is a left ideal of $R$ properly contained in $L$, so it can only be $0$. Therefore $\varphi$ is an isomorphism.

> In the first line, why can`t   we say  $LR = 0$?
>   surjective
>
> We know $ M = I m $ so $ \varphi $ is , why $\varphi$ is  bijective ($ker \varphi = 0 $) ?

Comment: I presume $R$ is unital. Then $LR\supseteq L\ne\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The line of reasoning isn’t true for all rings without identity, but it seems highly likely that the context is rings with identity.

Then $LR\supseteq L1\neq \{0\}$.

> We know $ M = I m $ so $ \varphi $ is surjective, why $\varphi$ is  bijective ($ker \varphi = 0 $).

Because $\ker\varphi$ is a proper submodule of the simple module $L$.