# Two minimal idempotents in simple ring are isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In the artice [*A short proof of the Wedderburn-Artin theorem - Tsiu-Kwen Lee*], the author says:

> Let $R$ be a simple ring.
> An idempotent $e\in R$ is called minimal if $eR$ is a minimal right ideal of $R$.
> Given two minimal idempotents $e,f \in R$,then $eR \cong fR$.

I think to prove that have to construct a function $\phi:eR \to fR$ such that $\phi$ is $R$-module isomorphic.

I try to define $\phi$ as $\phi(er)=fr,\forall r \in R$.Then it is easy to check $\phi$ is a $R$-module homomorphism.

And construct a function $\psi: fR \to eR$ by $\psi(fr)=er, \forall r \in R$.We can check that $\psi\phi=1_{eR}$ and $\phi\psi=1_{fR}$.

Hence $\psi$ is the inverse function of $\phi$,so we know $\phi$ is bijection.
The prove is complete.

But I feel something weird.I don't use any condition about idempotent and simple ring.
Does my prove have any wrong?

Comment: @rschwieb Thank you!I have edited my post.

Comment: You can't just define $\phi(er)=fr$, you have to check that this is well-defined. Suppose $er=er'$. Why do you have $fr=fr'$?

Comment: [Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2604817/let-r-be-a-simple-ring-having-a-minimal-left-ideal-l-then-every-simple-r). As @rschwieb wrote there, the proof is not suitable for nonunital rings (as are considered in the paper), but maybe this could be overcome using the idempotents.

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist Thank you!I will try.

Comment: @CaptainLama Thank you for finding my wrong place!

Comment: Thank you for improving your question